# When tap on page of epub file How to change font size of text for epub file for iphone application?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, epub

I am trying to parse epub file into UIWebView. I parsed successfully. But i can't able to set font size. Means when tap on epub file page the font needs to be increased. And I added UISearchBar but if i entered text it can't able to find. So please give me any suggestions and if anyone have code regarding that can u people provide me. 
Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 3):

use this code it will work.

```
-(void)addbtnClicked:(id)sender{

if([sender tag] == 1 && textFontSize < 160){
    //textFontSize = (textFontSize < 160) ? textFontSize +5 : textFontSize;
    textFontSize = textFontSize+5;


    NSLog(@"+ btn");}
else if(textFontSize > 10){
    NSLog(@"- btn");
   // textFontSize = (textFontSize > 50) ? textFontSize -5 : textFontSize;
    textFontSize = textFontSize-5;


}
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", 
                      textFontSize];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
[jsString release];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to increase and decrease the font size.Take two button for increase font and decrease font. Add this code in increase font size button. Please check this code.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults1 setBool:YES forKey:@"btnM1"];
[userDefaults1 synchronize];
textFontSize = (textFontSize < 140) ? textFontSize +5 : textFontSize;
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", textFontSize];
[_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

and then in your `webviewDidFininshLoading:` add this

```
NSUserDefaults *menuUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] if([menuUserDefaults boolForKey:@"btnM1"]){
[_webview setOpaque:NO];
[_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
NSString *jsString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'black'"];
[_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString2];
```

Similarly you can decrease font by replacing +5 with -5 in decrease font button action and changing key value of course.
Hope this will help.